# Card with gradient, image & Text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So I need a card with rounded corners with an image as a background with some darkened areas at the top and bottom so that the text on top is visible. This is the kind of image that I want.

[image: required design]

I have successfully made this design but I am using `Stacks` for this. My code currently is something like this:

```
    return Container(
      width: cardWidth,
      height: cardHeight,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 2,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: myRadius),
        child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                backgroundImageContainer(),
                backgroundGradientContainer(),
                foregroundItems(),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
```

My Gradient container is something like this:

```
    backgroundGradientContainer() {
      return Container(
        width: cardWidth,
        height: cardHeight,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: myRadius,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
              Colors.transparent,
              Colors.transparent,
              Colors.transparent,
              Colors.transparent,
              Colors.transparent,
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

My Image container is something like this:

```
    backgroundImageContainer() {
      return Container(
        width: cardWidth,
        height: cardHeight,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: myRadius,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(widget.myUser.profile_pic_url),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Now in my pov, this is too inefficient. Is there any other easier way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use the `Stack` widget here because you can set gradient and background image in the first `Container` itself. Like this:

```
return Container(
  width: cardWidth,
  height: cardHeight,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: myRadius,
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
          Colors.transparent,
          Colors.transparent,
          Colors.transparent,
          Colors.transparent,
          Colors.transparent,
          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
        ],
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      ),
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(widget.myUser.profile_pic_url),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: Card(
    elevation: 2,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: myRadius),
    child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: foregroundItems()
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Nope, this is not working. As you can see the result here. https://ibb.co/n3V693w